# Debugger in CodeLite not showing Local variables

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, codelite

I have installed CodeLite 14.0.0 for C++. It is on the Windows platform. The Debugger section does not display the local variables while debugging. From the image, it can be seen that the program is a simple one so it runs perfectly and gives the output. 
Since it is a simple program, so it works well and gives the output

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works for me-
1. uninstall your current MinGW and also delete its environment path
2.install version 8.1 from link below add its bin path to environment variables
3.scan for MinGw in Codelite and Done...

This worked perfectly for me

Credit-https://github.com/eranif/codelite/issues/2458   [eranif]

You can download it from here:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/installer/mingw-w64-install.exe